# Flutter- logistics requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.2.2, version solving failed. exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter logistics application, that basically tracks products.
But, I am facing an issue in my `pubspec.yaml` file

The Code inside `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: logistics
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.2.2' 

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  scoped_model: ^2.0.0
  # map_view: ^0.0.14
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  http: ^1.1.2
  intl: ^0.18.1
  mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0
  syncfusion_flutter_maps: ^18.2.44-beta
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.5.4+2

  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Error :
[smartailogistics] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.2.

Because logistics requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.2.2, version solving failed.
exit code 1

I tried resetting the SDK version of Flutter, But it did not work.

I tried resetting the SDK version of Flutter to 2.12.0 and
[Scoped Model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model)

I also did `flutter upgrade`, But still shows same error

I am unable to figure out, what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below means that the dart SDK should be less than 3.2.2.

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.2.2'
```

changing the max constrain to 4.0.0 should fix it. you may also consider pumping the min constrain to 3.0.0.

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'
```